# Calculating network throughput

Tags: tcp, ip, ethernet, throughput

suppose i have a 4MBits network and i want to calculate the data throughput, this is considering the max transfer rate minus overhead from ethernet/IP/TCP headers.
Reading on the web i found out that the MSS ( maximum segment size) of a TCP segment is 576 - 20 - 20, these last two being TCP and IP headers overhead, resulting in a 93% of data, meaning i will be only using 93% of my 4MBits link to transfer data. Now where's the link ayer overhead? Shouldn't it be added as well? If im not wrong an ethernet header is around 46 bytes so the final sum would be 576 - 20 - 20 - 46 = 490, resulting in an 85% data throughput, but am i doing something wrong?

Comment: That's the minimum MSS. Typically it's going to be something like 1460.

Comment: Still doesn't answer the question, should it or not count the link layer header to calculate the maximum data throughput of a link if TCP is used?

Comment: I didn't attempt to answer your question per se. I only answered the *but am i doing something wrong*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just work bottom up. Regular ethernet frames (no jumbo frames, no vlan tagging) are `1542 bytes` in total and can have a payload of `1500 bytes`. An Ipv4 header without options is `20 bytes` and a TCP header without options also `20 bytes`. So you end up with `1460 bytes` possible payload of a `1542 byte` link-layer frame. So your efficiency is `1460/1542=0.9468223086900129`, resulting in a maximum throughput of `3.7872892347600517Mbps`.

Notice however this will usually be lower. This is the theoretical maximum rate for a continuous stream you can get on a full duplex link, after the TCP session is established and when you're the only user of that link. Also note that as soon as you're sending at a slightly higher rate for some time your link will get congested, you will see drops and your actual TCP throughput might drop significantly because of slow-start.

If the link is wireless (802.11) the calculation becomes a lot more complex because of RTS/CTS mechanisms, but it's about `/2` for only one active user and that's without  incorporating loss, which is unrealistic.

Comment: Should we consider also the ack packets from tcp consuming part of the link? Even if they have no payload they still have the headers, reducing the throughput even more, am i right?

Comment: No, if you're continuously streaming and delay ACK's (should be default), the ACK will be included in the header of a regular data packet.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the protocol can impact network throughput and much more than simply the packet overhead.  You mention that you want to measure throughput on an Ethernet/IP/TCP network but the impact of packet overhead of those protocols is NOT the only thing to consider.  TCP is a connection-oriented protocol and uses ACK's to signal if a packet has been received or not.  user1777914 missed the mark about ACK's  but was on to something - they do not take up any more SPACE but they can DELAY the transmission of packets.  As latency increases the overall network throughput can decrease based on how often the application or hosting OS expects a response.

W. Richard Stevens has written an AMAZING book on TCP/IP.  [Here](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.223.1.249/1/) is an except that explains theoretical TCP performance, what impacts it and how it is calculated.

There too is the Nagle algorithm helps with latency but if disabled can slow down throughput.